# How to export a model from Blender 3.6 to Unity 2022?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender, unity3d-editor

When I save the model in FBX format and throw it into the unit, then all the materials delete.For my model I use material, but not texture.What should I do? Does it need to be protected separately? If so, how? Or maybe the versions of the programs are not compatible Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this the blender renderer or cycles? In general I think node based materials are not really supported in FBX (might be completely wrong here though - might be also just a limitation on Unity import) ... have you tried to simply recreate the material graphs in Unity using the [Shader Graph](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/introduction-to-shader-graph)?

Comment: might also be interesting for you: https://forum.unity.com/threads/beta-blender-nodes-in-unity.1249171/

Answer (score 5):

As a game developer or programmer, first, we should understand how computers and softwares work. To explain the problem, let's start with a simple example.

Imagine that I'm using Photoshop and painting an apple. When I finish my work, I want to save it to a file on the disk, because I am working in RAM while painting. Whenever I click the save button, Photoshop saves my work to the disk, defaulting to the PSD file format. However, the file extension here doesn't really matter; it's just a bunch of bytes on the disk that Photoshop can easily and fully read. What happens if I save my work in the JPG format? Photoshop can also save it as JPG, but in doing so, I will lose a lot of information about my work, such as layers and colors. Why is this the case? It’s because the JPG format has standards and limitations. I can't save all aspects of my work and am limited by JPG's standards. We can refer to this as a loss of information.

Now, let's discuss Blender and FBX. The situation is quite similar. You can't save all of your work in the FBX format. You are limited by FBX's standards and will lose some information about your materials. With this loss of information, you import your work into Unity. Please be aware of this as it constitutes the first problem.

The second problem lies in the Render Engines. Blender uses its own render engine, while Unity uses a different one. They don’t employ the same render engine, so the shaders will be different. This means that they utilize different materials, and even if you can transfer your work from Blender to Unity, you will lose some information again.

In conclusion, if you don't want to lose data, you need to create middleware software or a plugin for Blender and Unity. Your plugin should assess and compare the Unity shader that you are using with the Blender shader that you are using, and then facilitate the data transfer.

As a final note, every computer program uses different data structures. There is no direct transfer from one software to another. In your example, you are limited to the FBX data standard. If you learn the details of the FBX standard, then you can understand what is wrong or what is missing in the FBX file.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and reads like an AI-generated answer.

Comment: I read the question. And I noticed that the questioner has the lack of knowledge about the softwares and data structues on the computers. So, I gave a detailed answer about the problem.

I'm not a native English. Thus, I used AI to fix my grammer problems in my answer. If it is forbidden, I did not know, please delete my answer then.

My opinion about the AI: AI has been invented. And I can use it to make up for my shortcomings, right? If AI helps in communication between us, what is the problem about it?

Comment: If you used AI only to fix your grammar, then it's ok. But using answers purely generated by AI is discouraged, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Comment: I did some quick research. And I think I can use Grammarly. It only fixes the grammar issues. It does not touch the content of the text. Chatbots are changing some sentences. I'm happy that this conversation has gone to a positive solution and new knowledge for me. Thanks for the comment.